# WebStorm - Scope - Hide top-level directory

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I've set up a scope to basically show the contents of the `src` directory in my project:

```
file:src//*
```

This works as intended, but it should the `src` directory itself, like this:

- src

  - index.js
  - another.js

Is there a way to get it to remove the extra directory, so it'd show something like this:

- index.js
- another.js

Note, in this case, there aren't other siblings of `src`, so `src` is completely extraneous.

---

For those curious why, I actually am working on a project which is broken into about 10 different modules (which would be published independently), so I've pulled in each as a Source Root. I'm using a scope to hide the extraneous files I don't need to touch that often (`package.json` and the like). By removing `src`, it makes it slightly more compact, making it a little easier to navigate.

Comment: Seems it's not possible. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.